# How to model the force between conducting charged spheres due to induced polarisation in self assembling wires

Tags: electrostatics, simulations

I am trying to build a computer simulation for self-assembling wires. The setup is that a load of ball bearings of equal radius are placed in a dielectric fluid move in a strong electric field and form interesting emergent structures. The main physics is induced electrostatic charge on the surface of the spheres which causes attraction and if the balls are touching, then they repel due to having the same charge. I'm not a physics student and, to be honest not that smart, so please excuse any naivity in my questions, which are:

1. What is the formula distribution of charge that is induced on the surface of conducting sphere i caused by each other ball bearing?
   My answer: Assuming balls are distance r apart from centre to centre and of radius R. The voltage will be the vector sum of each of the other charges. (ie V=kqr). Capacitance of sphere is 4*PI*permitivity*R. Therefore as Q = CV, polarised charge on one side = 4*PI*permitivity*R * qr and on the other side it's the opposite... pretty sure that is wrong!! But that's sadly my best guess even after reading about electrostatics. Once I'v got the induced charge on one end of the sphere, then presumably that charge is distributed so that at the equator it is zero.
   Also, I think this must assume that r >> R, whereas in fact, the balls are quite close to each other. I found this article which I think contains the answer, but it's too complex for me to understand. https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2012.0133
   I don't know if it is against rules to ask for interpretation?
   To make it more precise, if I model the surface of each sphere as a number of discrete sections I could use this to figure out the induced charge on each part of the sphere from all the other sections of all the other ball bearings.
2. What is the best most accurate way to model the force on each ball bearing?
   My answer would be to use the above approach with Coulomb's law.

Many thanks for your help! It's a really interesting problem and the physics seems to be richer than first expected.

References:
Video of self-assembling wires: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeHWqr9dz3c
The original article is: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep15044
They actually tried to do a computer simulation, but it failed to produce the experimental topology due to over-simplification in their model. I think they failed to model the polarisation correctly. https://doi.org/10.1038/srep41621